# js , html5, css, cross browser issues 

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, cross-browser

i was in the process of doing a fun project gathering music info/playable links etc using different api's . I was testing simultaneously on Firefox 3.6, 4 and chrome for looks and js corrections (and js lint ofcourse). this morning i fired up IE (IE 9) and bam!! everything is absent. IE9 seriously messed up with my css and then some problem with conditional compilation. i am using jquery and jquery UI.

i checked for json2.js 
and divx webplayer issues.. .but that do not works out .. (even added a var JSON = JSON || {};
var allowsCC = /*@cc_on!@*/!1; as suggested by people here in other posts)

can someone take a quick glance 
http://eargasm.x10.mx/  (temporary link)

PS: site is very buggy in terms of functionality (its been 20 days only and i am 21 days old in web world, so questions might be silly ), wait it to load till u see an error 100 (left below) and reload once more(some odd problems, i am working on them), at times double clicks instead of clicks are binded.

EDIT: IE9 is placing them far below... if we highlight a part and drag mouse towards below..

Comment: [Validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feargasm.x10.mx%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: thanks Quentin, it helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validate your HTML as Quentin commented.

Moreover,  tag comes inside  tag
Use doctype declarations. They are very helpful

Comment: thanks a lot , better already ...!! but threw up one of my button elsewhere and messed up with css3 .. still working out .. i can see some hope here !!